# How to get full Xpath of element returned by find() method in element tree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm working with an xml that gets pretty deep. I'm able to extract a certain element via:

`parent_element = tree.find(f'.//ns:{tag}[@eId="{eId}"]', namespaces = nsmap)`

Is there any way I can reconstruct the full Xpath of the returned element?

Thanks

Comment: If you cannot use lxml, maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68239457/407651

Answer (score 2):

if you use lxml, try: [getpath](https://lxml.de/apidoc/lxml.etree.html?highlight=getpath#lxml.etree._ElementTree.getpath).

> getpath(self, element)
>
> Returns a structural, absolute XPath expression to find the element.
>
> For namespaced elements, the expression uses prefixes from the
> document, which therefore need to be provided in order to make any use
> of the expression in XPath.
>
> Also see the method getelementpath(self, element), which returns a
> self-contained ElementPath expression.