# How to get the xml element path by using xml.etree.elementtree instead of lxml?

Tags: python-3.x, xml-parsing, xml.etree

I'm new to python, I'm using **xml.etree.elementtree** module to parse the xml file. while parsing trying to get the xml element path which is having the value.

for example:

```
<root>
  <a>
     <b>Hello</b>
     <b1>Hi</b1>
  </a>
  <c>
    <d>Welcome</d>
    <e>Sample xml</e>
  </c>
</root>
```

here I want to get the element path, which is having value

```
root/a/b
root/a/b1
root/c/d
root/c/e
```

like in *lxml* module we can get it with the help of *getelement()*. But, how can we achieve the same by using the module xml.etree.elementtree.

Comment: you can use `iter()` on root and see which tags have values

Comment: lxml has no method called `getelement()`. I think you mean `getelementpath()` or `getpath()`. https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._ElementTree-class.html

Comment: This question looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/68215347/407651