# Python, using xml.etree.ElementTree to get absolute Xpath of an element, using indexes

Tags: python, xml, lxml, elementtree, xml.etree

Stuck on something and don't see it in the documentation. I'm trying to query very large XML files based on the text value of   , etc. and one of the values I would love to get when querying is the complete absolute path, including indexing information.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xmlfile = *pathtoFile*
tree = ET.parse(xmlfile)
root = tree.getroot()

for elm in root.findall("./sequence/media/video/track/clipitem/file/name[.='Graphic']../../name"): 
    CurrentClip = (elm.text)
    Graphics_Name_List.append(CurrentClip)

for elm in root.findall("./sequence/media/video/track/clipitem/file/name[.='Graphic']../../start"): 
    CurrentClip = (elm.text)
    Graphics_Start_List.append(CurrentClip)
```

The above code will append  of all graphics to a list named "Graphics_Name_List", and the  of all graphics to a list named "Graphics_Start_List", by using (elm.text)

What I'm really hoping to find is a way to include the entire absolute path to these elements that I've queried. I found 2 interesting answers elsewhere on StackOverflow, but they do not include indexing.

[Capture all XML element paths using xml.etree.ElementTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68215347/capture-all-xml-element-paths-using-xml-etree-elementtree)

[Get Xpath dynamically using ElementTree getpath()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13136334/get-xpath-dynamically-using-elementtree-getpath)

Both of those functions return Xpath like this:

./sequence/media/video/track/clipitem/filter/effect/parameter/name

But what I really require is an Xpath like this, with indexing:

./sequence[0]/media[0]/video[0]/track[3]/clipitem[56]/filter[0]/effect[0]/parameter[0]/name[0]

What I'm really trying to do is pull which Track/Clipitem it appears in (Track 3? Track 5?), but I'm currently finding that to be tough.

So far I believe I'm only using features from xml.etree.ElementTree... I know there's a feature in lxml that can do this, but I also don't know how to mix modules and became a little confused when passing an element value that had been parsed in ET.parse(xmlfile) into etree.Xpath(elm)... is that even possible?

Comment: If there is a feature in lxml, why not just use it? Avoid "mixing modules".

Comment: Could you please explain to me how to do that? Do I have to build an entirely parallel set of varilables? As you can see from my code I've already built

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xmlfile = *pathtoFile*
tree = ET.parse(xmlfile)
root = tree.getroot()

So when I build for loops to query, I'm using my "root" variable from ET.parse. Do I just build the same thing along side it but using all lxml and then build for loops referencing like... for elm in root2.findall()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1577495/407651

Comment: Sorry I meant how to implement in my script? Please see above comment. Thanks.

Comment: You asked for a way to get the absolute xpath of elements and I provided a link. That solution uses lxml only. That means you should too. Do not try to mix `lxml.etree` objects and `xml.etree.ElementTree` objects.

Comment: "an Xpath like this, with indexing: `./sequence[0]/media[0]/video[0]/track[3]/clipitem[56]/filter[0]/effect[0]/parameter[0]/name[0]`": interesting, last time I looked, in XPath the first index was 1 and not 0. So that example doesn't make a lot of sense with all those `[0]` predicates.

Comment: @martinhonnen You are correct, sorry for the mistake. Every line I have to change gears cause Python first index is [0] and XPath first index is [1], so returning results from xpath into an array and then indexing the array, I have to keep track of if my for loop starts at 0 or 1.        Regardless, my question is how to get absolute path when querying in ElementTree.